# Pass JWT in Header

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, json-web-token, express-jwt

I am learning JWT with NodeJs. I am stuck at passing the JWT in header actually i do not know how to do this.

**index.js file**

```
var express = require('express'),
 app = express(),
 routes = require('./routes'),
 bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
 path = require('path'),
 ejs = require('ejs'),
 jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); 
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.post('/home',routes.loginUser);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});

app.get('/home',function(req, res) {
  jwt.verify(req.token, 'qwertyu6456asdfghj', function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.sendStatus(403);
    } 
  });
});

 app.listen(3000,function(){
  console.log("Server running at Port 3000");
});
```

**routes/index.js file**

```
var  jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

exports.home = function(req, res){
  res.render('home',{error: false});
};

exports.loginUser = function(req, res) {
    var uname = req.body.Username;
    var pwd = req.body.Password;

    if(uname && pwd === 'admin'){
        res.render('home');

    var token = jwt.sign({ user: uname }, 'qwertyuiopasdfghj');
    console.log('Authentication is done successfully.....');
    console.log(token);
    }

    response.json({
        authsuccess: true,
        description: 'Sending the Access Token',
        token: token
    });
};
```

when i run the application i am getting the token in `console.log` but 
How can I pass token in header and store it in localStorage of browser?

Comment: This happens on the client side. Are you calling your express app from web? android? ios? each client needs to handle the tokens and attach it to requests as this header: "Authorization": "Bearer <token>" ('Bearer'is just a convention for using this with passport)

Comment: @ChicoDelaBarrio I know how can i do this ?

Comment: it depends on the client. I would recommend starting from using  postman [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) to test your requests

Comment: while i am sending response using `res.json({
        authsuccess: true,
        description: 'Sending the Access Token',
        token: token
    });`
I am getting this error  -> `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

Comment: it's because you can't use 'respinse.json()' after 'resposnse.render'. You can only respond once. This error is not JWT related

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you want to send the token to frontend but not in the body.

The **Recommended** way to do so is to use cookies. You can set the token in the cookie and it can be automatically accessed in front-end and in the backend.

```
res.cookie('tokenKey', 'ajsbjabcjcTOKENajbdcjabdcjdc');
```

Using authorization headers is also a good approach, but again, in front-end, you have to fetch the token from headers and then save in localStorage or cookie, which you don't have to do in case of cookie.

```
res.header(field [, value]);
```

Comment: Thanks but i solved before one week by `res.cookie('auth',token);` this only .

Comment: Oh sorry! It wasn't marked answered so I thought to do some help. Nvm

Answer (score 1):

As @ChicoDelaBarrio told you, it depends on the client. Postman is a good place to start checking your backend. But after you have your server working, you have to start working in your client side.

If you want a complete backend example about JWT in Node.js, with Refresh token included, I recomend you this post about it: [Refresh token with JWT authentication in Node.js](https://solidgeargroup.com/refresh-token-with-jwt-authentication-node-js)
Probably you can reuse most of the code. In this case the header is not created with BEARER, but with JWT at the beginning, but it works the same

Comment: Thanks i will look into it.