# How to Redirect a User without losing the Token in Express

Tags: javascript, express, discord

I am trying to add a Webinterface to my NodeJS Discord-Bot and decided to use Express for this. Now I have succesfully managed to set things up an managed to connect the Web-Socket with the Bot and was able to send my first Message through the Websocket into a Discord-Channel. Now I want to create different Sites in the Webinterface with each different uses. These are supposed to be linked through a neat Navbar at the Side of the Page. Once clicked, the user should be redirected to the new site without losing the Token he is authenticated with. For the Purpose of Testing the Token is '123456'. The User is supposed to be redirected by clicking on this Button

(layout.hbs)

```
<form action = "redirectInfo">
     <div class = "sidenav-element"><button type="submit">General Informations</button></div><br>
</form>
```

By clicking, the action "redirectInfo" is being triggered, which looks like this:

(webs.js)

```
this.app.get('/redirectInfo', (req, res) => {
        res.redirect(301, 'infoSite')
    })
```

I have tried using it both with the 301 and without which both leaves out the token .

This then redirects me to the 'infoSite' which is displayed using the following:

(webs.js)

```
this.app.get('/infoSite', (req, res) => {
   var _token = req.query.token

   if(!this.checkToken(_token)) {
       res.render('error', { title: 'Error', errtype: 'The given Token is invalid.'})
          return
       }

        res.render('infoSite', { 
           title: 'Webinterface',
           token: _token
        })

 })
```

However this results in the infoSite telling me my Token is invalid, while the Default Page perfectly works with the Same Methods. This is the Code from the Default Page:

(webs.js)

```
this.app.get('/', (req, res) => {
            var _token = req.query.token

            if(!this.checkToken(_token)) {
                res.render('error', { title: 'Error', errtype: 'The given Token is invalid.'})
                return
            }

            var chans = []
            this.client.guilds.cache.first().channels.cache
                .filter(c => c.type == 'text')
                .forEach(c => {
                    chans.push({ id: c.id, name: c.name})
            })

            res.render('index', { 
                title: 'Webinterface',
                token: _token,
                chans
            })

        })
```

In this Case "chans" can be ignored, as it's used to send Messages to Specific Channels in my Discord Server.

In both Cases _token is supposed to be Defined by The constructor and a function named checkToken (Code Attached)

```
constructor(token, port, client) {
        this.token = token
        this.token = token
        this.client = client
        this.app = express()
        this.app.engine('hbs', hbs({
            extname: 'hbs',
            defaultLayout: 'layout',
            layoutsDir: __dirname + '/layout'
        })) 
        this.app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
        this.app.set('view engine', 'hbs')
        this.app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
        this.app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}))
        this.app.use(bodyParser.json())

        this.registerRoots()

        this.server = this.app.listen(port, () => {
            console.log(`Webinterface started on Port: ${this.server.address().port}`)
        })
    }

    checkToken(_token) {
        return (_token == this.token)
    }
```

My Problem is, that whenever I leave the Default Page, the Token isn't being redirected with me and the Website tells me I've got an Invalid Token.

My Question is therefore, how can I redirect a client between multiple Sites, without him loosing the Token he is authenticated with. Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Where do you store your tokens? In memory? Or do you use some database such as MongoDB and Redis as a session storage?

Comment: My Tokens are currently not stored at all. There is only one Token (For Testing it's '123456') this Token is generated, once I start the Discord Bot. Code (bot.js):


`const webs = require('./ws/webs.js')

var ws = new webs('123456', 5665, client)`

Comment: Can you console log `req.query.token`? Is it there? If you mean losing the token, it means that the token is not there at all. Or do you mean token mismatch?

Comment: You may store the token in the header of the request or in the body. Have a look at this question for more information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48299135/pass-jwt-in-header.

Comment: @AvivLo I tried console.log(req.query.token) in both the Default-Site and the infoSite. Both had '123456' as an Output

Comment: Ok. Could you just do a strict equality check with an if statement instead of calling the method from the constructor? Just to rule out the possibility that `checkToken` is not right.

Comment: @HemantJain I am already storing the token in the body of the HTML-Sites by using the following: index.hbs: `<input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{token}}">`
@AvivLo checkToken seems to be right after checking with the if statement.